# Simple PWM vs Buck Topology for Motor Speed Control

Tags: buck

A simple triangle wave generator with a comparator can be used to create PWM that can be fed to a switch for controlling the speed of the motor. 
    Alternatively, by using any buck controller integrated circuit such as TI LM3485 we can step down the voltage to a defined value, all the PWM and controlling feedback topologies integrated inside the chip.
    My question is, given the fact PMDC motors which are not so sensitive to momentary spikes (at least in my case), isn't the first method also reliable for speed control? 
Except for the efficiency is their any other reason as to why one should go with the second option where we use inductor in the circuit?

Comment: IMO you have messed all, who told you to use buck converter to control DC motor?

Comment: The first method uses an inductor but that inductor is part of the motor's windings.

Answer (score 2):

Neither circuit actually controls motor speed, only the *voltage* sent to the motor. However the speed of a PMDC motor is proportional to supply voltage, so varying the motor voltage is commonly called 'speed control' even though it doesn't actually set the speed directly.

The main difference between the two methods is that the LM3485 produces a regulated output voltage, whereas with simple PWM switching the motor just receives a proportion of the supply voltage. If the supply voltage is not stable then the LM3485 will be able to hold the motor speed more constant.

The main disadvantage of using a buck regulator is increased loss in the inductor. This becomes a problem with high power motors, because you need a physically large inductor to keep losses down. In a simple PWM circuit the motor's internal inductance is used to smooth out current flow. This causes increased power loss in the motor, but this loss is usually small relative to other motor losses (provided that the PWM frequency is high enough - not always achieved in practice!).

Comment: Thank you for your reply, it really helped. I'll update when I'm done with the supply ,stating the final outcome.

Answer (score 0):

Akash,

I would use the PWM if you wanted the features including gate drive, current limit and ground referenced control signals.  But you are right, you don't need the inductor, the motor is the inductor.

AF

Comment: Thank you for your advice. I have to add such features and that's why I had the concern regarding the performance of simple PWM topology. Thanks for your time.